# DNS routing after PPTP connection

Tags: dns, vpn, pptp, dnsmasq, resolvconf

I use a PPTP VPN to connect to my work's environment, but don't know how to configure DNS resolution the way it seems appropriate.

When I connect via *Network Manager* I get two servers in `/etc/ppp/resolv.conf` and `mywork.com.br` as a search domain in `/etc/resolv.conf`. While it allows me to resolve names in that network it also seems to redirect all DNS requests through the servers pushed by the PPTP server.

Differently, when I connect with `pon mywork` no change is done to the DNS settings, but I lose the remote name resolution that I have in the first case.

So, how can I manage to keep both DNS servers working? I mean, I'd like to resolve `machine.mywork` through the PPTP DNS server and everything else through my ordinary server.

Here's my `/etc/ppp/peers/mywork`:

```
pty "pptp vpn.mywork.com.br --nolaunchpppd"
name me@mywork.com.br
remotename mywork
require-mppe-128
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
ipparam mywork 
nodefaultroute
```

I'm running 14.04 LTS. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: More information is needed though - what DNS routing changes are you *expecting* to see, and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to run a local DNS server that can forward queries to other DNS servers based on subdomain/domain.

Ubuntu's network-manager already runs a local DNS server (`dnsmasq-base`) however the required options are not available so disable it then install and configure the full `dnsmasq` package as follows:

1) Comment out `dns=dnsmasq` from `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

2) Restart network-manager: `sudo service network-manager restart`

3) Install `dnsmasq` package: `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`

4) Edit `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` and add:

```
server=/.mywork/VPN_DNS_IP
server=/#/INTERNET_DNS_IP
```

5) Restart dnsmaq: `sudo service dnsmasq restart`

Comment: This solution is not correct. "address" means "resolve all this TLD to this IP", instead "server" must be used to tell to ask ".mywork" TLD to "VPN_DNS_IP". So the correct usage will be :


  `server=/.mywork/VPN_DNS_IP`


Second line also not necesarry while rest will be resolved using DNS of your internet connection

Comment: In my case (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) `dns=dnsmasq` was not present in configuration file and reboot was required between steps 4 and 5 but the solution worked anyways.